# Expanding the function $f(x) = 1, 0 < x < 1$ in a series of the eigenfunctions?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, eigenfunctions

I have a problem that asks me to expand the function $ f(x) = 1, 0 < x < 1$ in a series of the eigenfunctions of the given problem. For example, one given problem is $y'' + 2y' + ( \lambda + 1)y = 0, y(0) = 0, y(1) = 0$.

What is meant by this ("expand the function in a series of the eigenfunctions of the given problem")? I don't understand what it is asking to do?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an eigenvalue/eigenfunction problem. Disregarding the endpoint conditions for the moment, the solutions of your problem have the form
$$
   y(x)=Ae^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+Be^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x).
$$
The solutions that satisfy $y(0)=y(1)=0$ are constant multiples of
$$
   y_n(x) = e^{-x}\sin(n\pi x),\;\; \lambda_n=n^2\pi^2,\;\;n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
In order to expand the constant function $f(x)=1$ in the eigenfunctions $\{ y_n \}$, you must find coefficients $C_n$ such that
$$
          1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n e^{-x}\sin(n\pi x) \\
        e^{x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n \sin(n\pi x).
$$
Using the orthogonality of the $\sin(n\pi x)$ functions on $[0,1]$ with respect to the integral gives $C_n$:
$$
      \int_{0}^{1}e^{x}\sin(n\pi x)dx = C_n\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx \\
       C_n = \frac{\int_{0}^{1}e^{x}\sin(n\pi x)dx}{\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx}.
$$
The series will converge to $1$ except at $x=0,1$, where it obviously converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Generically, this sort of problem has a sequence of eigenfunctions $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$; expanding a given function $f$ in terms of the eigenfunctions means determining scalars $c_n$ such that $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n f_n$. Strictly speaking this is an infinite linear system; to solve it, one should hope to find an *orthogonal* system of eigenfunctions with respect to some inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$, so that the $c_n$ are given by $\frac{\langle f,f_n \rangle}{\| f_n \|^2}$.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how this is done?

Comment: @Wyuw The "standard" example is Fourier series: for example, a Fourier sine series on $(a,b)$ amounts to doing this for the problem $y''+\lambda y=0$ with the boundary condition $y(a)=y(b)=0$. This problem is similar except there's a decaying exponential floating around as well.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will continue to try to tackle this problem.